# How do I display gmplot HTML inside jupyter lab notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, gmplot

I am currently trying to get some HTML to display inside jupyter lab notebook using ipython. I have got a way to work, however it requires me pushing the html file to github for github pages and then rendering the link inside jupyter lab.

The code that works:

```
IFrame(src='https://aasnani.github.io/test/', width=900, height=600)
```

However, I am trying to get it to work locally without having to push the file to GitHub.

I have tried:

```
IPython.display.IFrame(src=base_path + 'MN_Map.html', width=900, height=600)
IPython.display.HTML(filename=base_path + 'MN_Map.html')
IFrame(src=base_path + 'MN_Map.html', width=900, height=600)

HtmlFile = open(base_path + 'MN_Map.html', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
source_code = HtmlFile.read() 
display(HTML(source_code))
```

And none of these work. I have also enabled the gmaps and nbextensions in jupyter lab. Can someone explain why the first method works but the others don't? You can get the html file from the github link itself [here](https://aasnani.github.io/test/) or from the repo [here](https://github.com/aasnani/test).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi! Can you share what value you have saved in base_path?

Comment: @hbere base path is simply the absolute path to the HTML file on my local system.

Comment: Thanks. Here is a possible plan of action: try it with a simpler HTML file containing static text. If that fails, either local files are not accessible (security or configuration) or the file path is incorrect (user error). Otherwise, you’ve shown that it works in a simple case, and change the path to your MN_Map file. Now if your map works, you are done. But if it fails, JupyterLab for some reason (security or configuration) is not allowing your file’s interactive JavaScript to run.

Comment: If JupyterLab uses a similar security model to Jupyter Notebook, these security principles should carry over and might help explain the issue: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#our-security-model. And if so, you are probably best off uploading to an external server, like you have been doing with GitHub. To help with that, you might be able to find a tool to automate your uploads. ... I realize that none of this is a direct answer - it’s because I haven’t really used/found relevant documentation for JupyterLab, just Jupyter Notebook - but I hope the approach helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fundamental solution, but I found that this problem can be solved by using local server.

Example: launch server with [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), set `http://127.0.0.1:5500/<FILENAME>.html` as `src`

[Plot google map in jupyter notebook with Life Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwmSu.png)